# Py Regex with os library

Tags: python

I am trying to find regex as per my code below. The problem seems to be with the file path around open() function, although the error which pop's up present appropriate directory. Tried to find solution on my own, however seems like my beginner skills are not enough, to be more honest started to learn Python like 2 weeks ago. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
def unzip_guide():
        src_path = file_path()
        pattern = '\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{4}'
        for root, dir, file in os.walk(src_path):
            for f_ in file:
                if f_.endswith('zip'):
                    zippy = zipfile.ZipFile(src_path + '\\' + f_,'r')
                    zippy.extractall(src_path)
                    zippy.close()
        for root, dir, file in os.walk(src_path):
            for folder in dir:
                if folder.endswith('content'):
                    os.chdir(src_path + '\\' + folder)
                    cwd = os.getcwd()
                    for root,dir,file in os.walk(cwd):
                        for f_ in file:
                            myfile = open(f_,'r')
                            matches = []
                            reg = reg = re.compile('\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{4}')
                            for line in myfile:
                                matches += reg.findall(line)
                            myfile.close()
```

Error is following:

```
File "C:/Users/XYZ/PycharmProjects/puzzle/puzzle.py", line 34, in unzip_guide
    myfile = open(cwd + '\\' + f_,'r')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\XYZ\\Downloads\\Complete-Python-3-Bootcamp-master\\Complete-Python-3-Bootcamp-master\\12-Advanced Python Modules\\08-Advanced-Python-Module-Exercise\\extracted_content\\AEITMYIRQLP.txt'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
                    for f_ in file:
                        myfile = open(f_,'r')
```

to:

```
                    for f_ in file:
                        myfile = open(os.join(root,f_),'r')
```

in order to join the file's name along with the path of the file.

Comment: I've got one more question- typical newb one. Why such functions as os.chdir or zipfile.ZipFile works fine with just simpy concatenating strings while open() function requires os.join(). Is there any partricular reason why that's happening?

Comment: @1Sh00t actually, `open()` can also use concatenated strings, there is no difference.